# Change data on RecyclerView ItemClick

Tags: android, onitemclicklistener, android-recyclerview

This is my Adapter class I want to click on a textview such that a dialog box appears when i enter a value the value gets stored in the textview . That is what I need but the values get entered in random positions.

```
public class myAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<myAdapter.ViewHolder> {

public List<Student> list;
static public Context context;


public myAdapter(List<Student> stdList) {
    this.list = stdList;

}

@Override
public myAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    context = parent.getContext();

    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_item, null);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemView);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.name.setText(list.get(position).getSname());

}


class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    protected TextView name;
    protected TextView amt;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Name);
        this.amt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.et_amount);
        this.amt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final int pos = getAdapterPosition();
                final AlertDialog.Builder inputAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                inputAlert.setTitle("Pay for picnic");
                inputAlert.setMessage("We need the amount to proceed");
                final EditText userInput = new EditText(context);
                userInput.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
                inputAlert.setView(userInput);
                inputAlert.setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        String userInputValue = userInput.getText().toString();
                        amt.setText(calc(userInputValue));
                        notifyItemChanged(pos);


                    }
                });
                inputAlert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = inputAlert.create();
                alertDialog.show();

            }
        });
    }

}

public String calc(String val) {

    int i = Integer.parseInt(val);
    if (i > 850) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Incorrect amount", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        i = 850 - i;
        Toast.makeText(context, "Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    String value = String.valueOf(i);
    return value;

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}
```

}

Comment: Does changing it to `this.amt.setText(calc(userInputValue));` work? If not, I'd recommend moving your Click Listener to your `onBindViewHolder`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will try to fill directly like this then it will not store value anywhere, and on scroll of recycle view or on notify change it will clear your data from view, so you need to first store value and then use it to display, I have just modified your onCLick method as below so just check it.

```
       @Override
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    String userInputValue = userInput.getText().toString();
                    amt.setText(calc(userInputValue));

                    final Student stud = list.get(pos);
                    stud.setAmt(calc(userInputValue));
                    notifyItemChanged(pos);


                }
```

And then also add one line to display data at onBindViewHolder as below,

```
       @Override
       public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) 
       {
             holder.name.setText(list.get(position).getSname());
             holder.amt.setText(list.get(position).getAmt());
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Moving your `OnClickListener` from the `ViewHolder` to the `onBindViewHolder`

Comment: No that part has no error. The value changes but when i scroll down the value changes automatically.

Comment: have you tried Moving your OnClickListener from the ViewHolder to the onBindViewHolder

Comment: OP, you would have much easier access to the position from the onBindViewHolder.

Comment: Yes, I tried that what I needed was to set the changed text as setAmount . THanks